# PHP:Trying to get html form to send email, if captcha completed correctly

Tags: php, email, recaptcha

Here is the HTML of the mail form:

in the head:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

In the body:

```
    <form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Phone Number</p> <input type="text" name="number"<br/><br/>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my site key"></div><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send"><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</form>
```

Here is the entire mail.php file:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Phone Number: $number";
$recipient = "me@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= 'To: $recipient';
$mailheader .= 'From: $email \r\n';
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    die("Please fill in all forms.");
  } else {
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      die('Invalid email.');
    } else {
      if (strlen($number) == 10) {
        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey = "priv key";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                        $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
         if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
                "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
        } else {
                mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
            die("Thank You!");
        }
    } else {
        die ("Please enter a 10 digit phone number with no hyphens.");
        }
  }
}
?>
```

So far when uploaded to my file server it always throws back a "thank you" unless all fields arent filled out. As you can see I am trying to use google's recaptcha to keep robots from mailing spam as well as doing checks of my own to make sure the forms are filled out correctly. The problem is I don't get any email. Any help in this matter is much appreciated.

Comment: Then this might be more of a PHP mail issue than a captcha issue. Since the mail isn't arriving at all. Have you checked the mail log of any errors etc?

Comment: why the upside down logic?, `if (!$resp->is_valid) {` will be true for a false value...

Comment: Keep getting "The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again.(reCAPTCHA said: incorrect-captcha-sol)" so I switched it to test if the email would send out. Haven't checked the log, trying to find it now.

Comment: print $_POST when form is submitted, print_r($_POST); Check your post values and compare with what you expect. Check recaptcha_check_answer function so you know what you should expect.

Comment: so when I print post I get the responses from the text fields in the html along with [g-recaptcha-response] followed by a whole bunch of random numbers and letters, not sure what to make of it. I think googles documentation said it was a JSON object that was being returned, just not sure how to check that information for the boolean value of true or false.